# BigQuery SQL extract string before 3rd occurance of /

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a BQ table with URLs in one column. However I would like to extract only the domain name.

For example I have the following strings

```
http://u.example.com/g/foo
http://www.exmple.com/g/bar
```

and I want to extract everything before the 3rd occurence of '/'
with the output looking like the following:

```
http://u.example.com
http://www.example.com
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `REGEXP_EXTRACT`:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(col, '^(http://[^/]+)') AS url_fragment
FROM yourTable;
```

A more general pattern to cover different URLs might be this:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(col, '^(\w+://[^/]+)') AS url_fragment
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: hey, what if i have urls  that differ in terms of the http://, such as https://. is there a wildcard option here to sub it with?

Comment: @sharkorama Check my updated answer.  You may make the pattern as restrictive as you like.  You might also find the pattern `^https?://[^/]+` to be acceptable.